# What is the best way to validate a given regex bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm looking for something equivalent to the following Python snippet in bash:

```
import re

try:
    re.compile('[')
    is_valid = True
except re.error:
    is_valid = False
```

Comment: Valid *where* exactly? There are many flavors; so just call a Python (or perl or..) script to do approximately what is shown, probably using either stdout or the exit status.

Comment: @user2864740 Bash uses POSIX Extended REs.

Comment: *Update the question so it focuses on one problem only.* But it does already? I don't get why it was closed. It's a perfectly clear and focused question.

Comment: @Shawn. Yeah (mostly). The close reason is just plain wrong. I could understand, "Needs details or clarity", but that's down to (I guess) the OP being a non-Native English speaker. I'm gonna vote "Edit and reopen" from the review.

Answer (score 1):

From the [bash documentation on `[[` and `=~`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b):

> The return value is 0 if the string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise. If the regular expression is syntactically incorrect, the conditional expression’s return value is 2.

Which leads to...

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

test_re() {
    [[ x =~ $1 ]]
    [[ $? -ne 2 ]]
}

for re in "$@"; do
    if test_re "$re"; then
        printf "%s\n" "$re is valid"
    else
        printf "%s\n" "$re is not valid"
    fi
done
```

Example:

```sh
$ bash demo.sh "[" "[a-z]"
[ is not valid
[a-z] is valid
```